# padding left & right in flex item chrome vs firefox

Tags: css

Chrome and Firefox seem to interpret padding different in flex box items. I fixed it before by wrapping the item but it dosen't seem to work in this case.

```
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item">i</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item">i</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item">i</div>
    </div>
  </div>


.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  padding: 100% 50%;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/papuvidulepa/1/edit

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Why is this happening and what should I do in order to have same padding on the items in chrome and firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a CSS reset. Go to http://www.cssreset.com/ and get one of the resets. Then create a css file with one of the codes, and link that css file into your html document. Now, every time someone goes to the webpage (regardless of the browser), it will reset all pre-determined margins and paddings, and you can set your own with a new css file.